# In Nemo's treeview, I want a "Open with..." in the right-click menu

Tags: nemo

In Nemo, I like right-clicking on a folder and opening with... Visual Studio Code.

But I don't get an "Open with" option in the context menu when I right click in the tree view on the left.

Is there some way I can get this?

Thanks.